# Understanding an algebra isomorphism resulting from the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field, and let $s_1, ..., s_n$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$. The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials tells us that

> Each symmetric polynomial in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$ can be written as a polynomial of $s_1, ..., s_n$. Moreover, the polynomials $s_1, ..., s_n$ are algebraic independent.

Hence, if we define $k[X_1, ..., X_n]^{S_n}$ to be the set of symmetric polynomials in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$, then we have an algebra isomorphism $f \colon k[X_1, ..., X_n]^{S_n} \to k[t_1, ..., t_n]$ that is determined by $f(s_i)=t_i$.

My question is, $k[t_1, ..., t_n]$ is basically the same thing as $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$. By the preceding argument, the we will have $k[X_1, ..., X_n]=k[X_1, ..., X_n]^{S_n}$, which is weird. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You shouldn't write "basically the same thing", you mean "isomorphic". And things can be isomorphic without being equal. The group of even integers $2\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to (basically the same thing as?) the group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ but they are not equal.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I got it. Thanks a lot!